# Removing unwanted codes from mysgli query result

Tags: php, mysqli

please help.

I was trying to query a mysqli database to display part of my blog articles on my main page using php. It output a messy character as shown on the link. www.myimcm.com (unwanted commas and stuffs like that. The simple code for this was:

```
 $q ="SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_content,' ',130) AS post,(post_title) AS title,ID AS id FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='post' ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 1";
$r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); // Run the query.

if ($r) { // If it ran OK, display the records.
    echo '<h2>LATEST FROM OUR GUIDES</h2>'; 
// Fetch and print all the records:
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
     echo"<p class='title'>". ($row['title'])."</p>";
     echo nl2br($row['post']);

echo '<a href="http://guides.myimcm.com/wp"> Continue reading</a>';

}
    mysqli_free_result ($r); // Free up the resources.  

} else { // If it did not run OK.

    // Public message:
    echo '<p class="error">The are no latest from our blog. We apologize for any inconvenience.</p>';

    // Debugging message:
    echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '<br /><br />Query: ' . $q . '</p>';

} // End of if ($r) IF.
mysqli_close($dbc); // Close the database connection.
```

Comment: Looks like an encoding issue, whats the database collate?

Comment: I think you're having problem with encoding. try to change the double quote manually to your database. I mean remove the double quote and replace it to a new one. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

use utf-8 encoding in your webpages.
Use this code in your head section.

```
 header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: @ Rohit, utf-8 encoding is declared on the page. you can view firebug. what do you think could be the problem again

Comment: try this mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");

Answer (score 0):

Your page claims to be encoded in UTF-8, but that is not true. It contains the following octets: `85`, `91`, `92`, `a0` which (on their own) are not valid UTF-8.
They are probably from one of the Windows-125x character encodings, such as [Windows-1252](http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP1252.TXT).

You need to set up your database to use the correct character encoding for the Database, Table, and connection. See the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset.html) and [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php) for details.

Comment: @ Nisse, ya. encoding is declared on the page. But your guide is not specific. kindly help with specified action. N/B not too long i start coding.

Comment: @user2989439: See the PHP Manual page on [character sets](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php).